# Unable to load UTM on mac m1

Tags: virtual-machine, apple-m1

I am having some issues running windows on UTM on a m1 mac.

I am trying to follow the following video on youtube::

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_hGkl9CSbM

I downloaded windows 11 ARM from the following:

https://tips2fix.com/windows-11-mac-m1/

- scroll down to "Download Windows 11 ARM" and donwloaded the "Windows11_InsiderPreview_Client_ARM64_en-us_22598.VHDX"

when I try to run UTM with that configuration i get stuck booting up app ( see screenshot)

[image: ERROR]

from other posts I learned that I need to disable EFI, but I dont have that setting. this is what its suppose to look like::

[image: missing config]

this is what my screen looks like::
[image: my config that has a missing config]

Any ideas how to fix this?